# Different productivity on view with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I've encountered an issue with productivity using the View limited with WHERE clause.

This code works immediately:

```
SELECT TOP(20) 
    m.Id, 
    m.Specs, 
    m.DefaultName, 
    m.NameLT, 
    m.NameEN, 
    m.NameTR
FROM multilang.vwOEvent AS m
WHERE CHARINDEX(N'we', m.NameEN) > 0
```

But when I'm using for example `WHERE CHARINDEX(N'we', m.NameLT) > 0` - using the similar but another field, I encounter with large (up to 30 seconds) delay.

The view is following:

```
CREATE VIEW multilang.vwOEvent
AS SELECT 
        a.EventID AS ID,
        a.Specs, 
        a.[Name] AS DefaultName, 
        lngEN.[Name] AS NameEN, 
        lngTR.[Name] AS NameTR, 
        lngAA.[Name] AS NameAA
    FROM      game.vwActiveOEvents a
    LEFT JOIN translation.OEvent lngEN ON lngEN.Specs = a.Specs and lngEN.LanguageID = 1
    LEFT JOIN translation.OEvent lngTR ON lngTR.Specs = a.Specs and lngTR.LanguageID = 2
    LEFT JOIN translation.OEvent lngAA ON lngAA.Specs = a.Specs and lngAA.LanguageID = 3
GO
```

The indexes on `translation.OEvent` are created. Additional code is obvious:

```
CREATE TABLE translation.OEvent (
    ID     BIGINT IDENTITY,
    LangID TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Specs  VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_translation_OEvent_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_OEvent
ON translation.OEvent (LangID, Specs)
INCLUDE ([Name])
ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE game.OEvent (
    ID     INT IDENTITY,
    Specs  VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    IDT    DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_game_OEvent PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE VIEW game.vwActiveOEvents
AS SELECT
        ID
        Specs
        [Name]
    FROM game.OEvent
    WHERE IDT > GETDATE()
GO
```

Will appreciate any advice and solutions. Index on view? Rebuilding of views?

The code is simplified, of course, but the removed parts contain business logic so are not interesting here.

Comment: Your where clause, `WHERE CHARINDEX(N'we', m.NameLT) > 0` is unable to make use of any index, hence an entire table scan is required... and hence its slow QED :)

Comment: Exactly, so what is the better solution?

Comment: There is no simple solution - there are [very complex solutions](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/09/sql-performance/sql-server-trigram-wildcard-search) :) the best thing is if you can find a way to pre-filter the results down to a manageable number.

Comment: The same lack of sargability is also true for `WHERE CHARINDEX(N'we', m.NameEN) > 0` though and you say that completes fast enough. What do the execution plans look like?

Comment: Martin makes a good point, and its still worth having an index on the column because, even though SQL Server will have to do an entire index scan, if there is an index with just that column in it, that is a lot less disk traffic to load than the entire table - believe me it can make a big difference. So SQL should do a scan of that index, then a seek of the clustered index to get the data for the matching records.

Comment: Please share the plans https://pastetheplan.com

Answer (score 0):

The difference in time is due to one of two factors:

- You may be measuring the time to the *first* row being returned, rather than to the last.
- The data volume associated with the different names might be radically different.

As mentioned in the comments, the `where` clause cannot use an index, due to the `charindex()` function.  That said, it would more colloquially be written using `LIKE`:

```
m.NameEN LIKE N'%we%'
```

However, that won't affect performance.

What can you do?  There are really no totally general solutions.  But here are some ideas:

- If you are really looking for exact equality, use `=`.  That is much more efficient.
- If you are always looking for the same string `'we'`, then you can use a computed column.
- If you are looking for a "word" in the string, then you can use a full-text index.

It is not clear if any of those conditions apply.

Comment: I improved the productivity using the advised by Live Query Statistic INDEX. Seems to be, that's enough.